# Difference between ConfigurationManager and ConfigurationSettings

Tags: c#, configurationmanager

What is the main difference between *System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"]* and *System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["key"]* ?

Comment: http://www.philosophicalgeek.com/2007/11/26/difference-between-configurationsettings-and-configurationmanager/

Comment: @HariGillala you might want to turn this into an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsettings.appsettings.aspx) is obsolete. [ConfigurationManager.AppSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx) is the replacement.

Comment: Why did become obsolete> @Christian.K

Comment: A possible answer is in the [link](http://www.philosophicalgeek.com/2007/11/26/difference-between-configurationsettings-and-configurationmanager/) @Hari Gillala posted as a comment to your question.

Comment: does it have any difference to process a configuration file?

Answer (score 12):

ConfigurationManager have more functional than ConfigurationSettings as list below
1. ConfigurationManager can access appsetting and connectionstring section
2. ConfigurationManager provide function that you can use to read and write config.
3. Permission by user level 
4. ...... and other that you can see on msdn

Refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that the ConfigurationManager object is in a different (DLL) assembly even though the namespace is the same.

ConfigurationManager 
Namespace:  System.Configuration
Assembly:  System.Configuration (in System.Configuration.dll)

ConfigurationSettings
Namespace:  System.Configuration
Assembly:  System (in System.dll)

Anton

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's a good idea to read the docs..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.configuration.configurationsettings(v=vs.80).aspx

Provides runtime versions **1.0 and 1.1** support for reading configuration sections and common configuration settings.

In other words, ConfigurationSettings class is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

‘System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings’ is obsolete: Obsolete means old or no longer in use. It has been replaced by System.Configuration!System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings’